# Tomcat 7 NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, concurrenthashmap, nosuchmethoderror

I am having trouble deploying a web application on tomcat 7. The application is compiled using JDK 7 so I configured tomcat to use JDK 7 by setting `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/` in `/etc/default/tomcat7`. When I run `top` I can confirm that tomcat is using java 7. However when I try to browse the application I get the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContext.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContextFacade.java:367)
    at com.intel.mtwilson.jpa.PersistenceManager.contextInitialized(PersistenceManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1980)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As far as I understand this method has different return types in [JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()) and [JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--) and tomcat is for some reason looking for the JDK 8 version even through it is configured to run in JDK 7. What is the reason for this? Do I have to configure anything else to make tomcat use JDK 7?

Comment: return types do no affect method signatures

Comment: Just to be sure I would look for ways to PRINT the version of Java somehow.

Comment: good to know, however I still have no clue why the method is missing

Comment: it could be a path issue. can you hit the same jvm with a console app that uses keySet()?

Comment: @GhostCat java -version says Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15) and the path in the process list matches the JDK 7 path, will try to print it somehow from code and add an update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is the the Tomcat you are using wasn't actually compiled with Java 7. [It looks like there are some Tomcat 7 builds floating around that were compiled with Java 8](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55554).

You should use Java 8. Even if Tomcat was compiled with Java 7, it should run on Java 8.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the installation from Ubuntu packages wouldn't run with Java 7 either but with Java 8.  It makes sense now.